# Turtlebot Gazebo Groovy

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-groovy, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read that the turtlebot gazebo simulator was broken.  Is it still broken?  Any time frame for it to be fixed?  Does anyone have a turtlebot (or even an icreate) working with gazebo?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61084/turtlebot-gazebo-groovy/) by [jforkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4213/jforkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to the fast development of Gazebo we haven't been able to implement a stable Turtlebot simulation for Groovy yet. We are currently targeting Hydro for that. If we get it working earlier, we will send a notification out on the [TurtleBot SIG mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-turtlebot). Join it to stay up to date!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it is ready. And even if it is ready some day I don't think it will come out so stable that you can implement everything you have been doing in the previous versions straight away (personal experience, I have been using ros-gazebo since diamondback. It does take some time for versions of ROS and Gazebo to come to a sync and by that time the next version of ROS will come out).

The most stable version for turtlebot simulation is fuerte 1.8.11. I have been using this for quite some time and it is very stable. Tele-operation to autonomous navigation, everything works fine. But even with this version, if your computer is not good enough (less than 2.2 Ghz proccessor, nvidia graphics etc) the simulation with turtlebot might crash often or just two wheels of the turtlebot will appear etc.. (run `top` on a terminal when running gazebo + nodelet manager + AMCL + rviz, you will understand).

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2